# Get server address in Java Web Start

Tags: java, java-web-start

How can I get server ip address in my JavaWS application, from which it was downloaded?

Thanks!

Comment: wouldn't it just be the client IP that you are running it on? I'm not sure what you mean by "which it was downloaded"

Comment: @JavaKungFu The server, not the client. (And you shouldn't be able to get the client IP address from the client unless privileged.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess, use [`BasicService.getCodeBase`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/javax/jnlp/BasicService.html#getCodeBase%28%29).

Comment: For a demo. & sample code of the BasicService, see my page at http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#bs

Comment: Thanks, but in my case it's don't work. ServiceManager.lookup("javax.jnlp.BasicService") throws exception. I use Spring and Spring rich client.

Comment: No ides what Spring is up to, but I did find this relevant page: http://spring-rich-c.sourceforge.net/1.1.0/apidocs/org/springframework/richclient/jnlp/JnlpPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html

Comment: I try my app from IDEA, and run it as desktop application. That's why ServiceManager.lookup("javax.jnlp.BasicService") didn't worked. JnlpPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer help me. @Tom Hawtin thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to get ahold of jnlp.jar and add it to your application.  I had to find it in the JDK samples and demos, which are distributed separately from the JDK.  I used [this samples and demos question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26137960/samples-and-demos-for-jdk-8u11) to find it.  I was able to get ahold of it with a URL like http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u11-b12-demos/jdk-8u11-windows-i586-demos.zip

With jnlp.jar on your classpath, use this code to get the URL of your application's codebase, which you can use to find the server hostname.

```
import javax.jnlp.*;

BasicService bs = (BasicService)ServiceManager.lookup("javax.jnlp.BasicService");
URL codebase = bs.getCodeBase();
```