# Finding "Samples and demos" for a specific JDK version

Tags: java, oracle

Oracle releases "Java SE Development Kit 8u20 Demos and Samples Downloads" alongside the [latest release](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) of the JDK, the latest is 8u20.

However on the [archive page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-javase8-2177648.html) only the main JDK packages are listed, I need to track down "Demos and Samples" specifically for 8u11.

Is there anywhere where these can be downloaded? I can't find any information about them on the oracle website or Googling for things such as "Java SE Development Kit 8u11 Demos and Samples Downloads" but can't find anything official.

Comment: You want us to google for you?

Comment: @SimY4 I tried googling for it, but couldn't find a satisfactory answer. That's why I'm asking the question.

Comment: The key is knowing WHAT to Google (Bing?  DuckDuckGo?) for.  This tends to run into the usual chicken-egg problem of "if I know what I was looking for, I'd have already found it".  But in this case, you do know one key thing about what you want: the file name!  So search for something like `jdk-8u172-windows-i586-demos.zip`.  You may get things that look vaguely shady, but since these are just sip files hopefully its fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you can guess the URL for the demos from the URL for the JDK, although Oracle do not appear to publish these officially.

JDK URLs

- http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u11-b12/jdk-8u11-linux-i586.rpm
- http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u11-b12/jdk-8u11-windows-i586.exe

Demos URL - add '-demos' to directory and filename, note windows demos are .zip not .exe.

- http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u11-b12-demos/jdk-8u11-linux-i586-demos.rpm
- http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u11-b12-demos/jdk-8u11-windows-i586-demos.zip

Comment: Been awhile, now they're at: `https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/java-archive-misc-downloads.html#jdk8demos`

Answer (score 3):

You don't need samples and demos for specific versions of jdk 8. The updates usually solve bugs or address security issues, which should not require new versions of the sample. So just use the available ones, and they should run fine.

Comment: sometimes they remove stuff; for instance, JavaDB and it's samples are gone in the latest version